# Access 2013 DB changes mysteriously to read only

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, labview

I work on a team of 10 test engineers all sharing a common Access 2013 database on a network server.  Everyone has read/write access to the DB.  Anyone can randomly open the database, write data to it, and then close it.  These actions are all done via Labview code "behind the scenes" to the user.  i.e. the user will start a particular test in Labview, the code (before starting the test) opens the shared DB, writes the test information to a table, then closes it before beginning the test.  We have now had 4 instances where someone will complain that they suddenly cannot access this shared DB.  Upon investigation we found that the DB had, somehow, turned into a read-only file and Labview's attempts to write to it are therefore failing.  My question is not "how do I make the database read/write again" (I've found other posts on that topic), but rather why does a read/write database suddenly become read-only?  We have tried to track this down to a failed "close DB" but have found nothing.  Whenever this happens there is no lock (.lck) file associated with the DB, so it doesn't appear to be locked.

Any ideas what may be happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the actual file being changed to read only, or just that it is opened in read-only mode within Access?

Comment: Good point, when I open the DB is has an information icon at the top of the file that says "READ-ONLY The database has been opened read-only.  You can only change data in linked tables.  To make design changes, save a copy of the database".

Comment: Between the 10 users who can "randomly open the database", does this also include opening the database from within Access (and not just via LabView code)?  Can or do any of the test engineers open the database to change the database schema?  Technically this can be done without opening Access, also using data definition library objects and methods.

Comment: Have you checked user rights to the containing folder?  They need read/write access to not only the file, but also the folder it is in.  What security context is the LabView code running?  Can it change, even for a single test engineer, perhaps running it on different computers with different OS or network security configurations?  Has something changed in this regard?

Comment: BTW, you supposedly know how to make it read/write again and are not interested in that detail, but you should still share exactly what you do to resolve the situation even if you don't know why it is happening.  A working solution can potentially indicate the cause, or can at least constrain the possible causes.

Comment: Has anti-malware software changed on the file server and/or clients?  Essentially anything that could interrupt file access to the database or its folder should be suspect.  With 10 engineers all using it at different times, this could be very likely.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and ideas.  Each engineer uses Labview to do these DB writes as part of the test code suite and should not be accessing the file directly, though I will follow up on that and insure that is indeed the case.  Also, these engineers are scattered across 4 different facilities and it could be that some sort of security re-config happened at one of the sites and not the others, again something to follow up on my end.

Comment: I should also clarify that while I said that I had found other posts with comments on how to change the file permissions, none of those actually helped me.  Right now our "work around" for this issue is to copy the DB to another name and point our Labview code to that new file.  Then everything works for another few months until this happens again.  Interesting note, however, is that at some point after our original DB goes read-only (weeks or months) I will check that DB again and it will no longer be read-only.  No idea why it went back to read/write.

Comment: The theory as to why the DB would go back to read/write was that someone had this DB in a locked/read-only state and was not allowing others to make changes.  However we went through everyone's permissions to the file & folder and everyone still had read/write access.  The 3rd time this happened we went so far as to systematically have everyone insure their Labview and Access were closed and even reboot their PCs, but nothing freed up the read-only DB.  However several weeks later when I checked the DB it was all of a sudden read/write again.

Comment: Since I doubt that there is one answer, just more suggestions and guesses:  1) I experienced similar problems with a database on a non-windows (linux) file server.  Although it "should" have worked just fine--permissions were valid--it would often prevent proper sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that different facilities access the DB file raises more red flags about probable network issues. A file-based Access database is **not** designed for reliable WAN access and many discourage such a configuration altogether.

Although you report no residual locking file, the *.ldb and *.laccdd files are only for the database engine's internal locking algorithms.  It works in conjunction with the file-server's OS locking mechanism.  I suspect that you have a database client whose OS file lock was not released properly, so the lock remains until timed out. That would explain your observations about delayed locking even after disconnecting other clients. You mentioned rebooting the client machines, but I suspect resetting the host file server would have immediately released the lock.

Of course a completely new server-based solution would be best in your situation, it is possible to produce an intermediate solution to avoid a complete overhaul of the LabView code.  Install and setup a SQL Server, then alter the Access database tables to be linked tables to a SQL backend.  Each LabView client would have their own copy of the Access DB linked to the same server.  This is a quick and dirty description and probably not the ideal, but it could eliminate this particular issue.

Comment: In the 'linked Access database' workaround, what happens if two clients try to make conflicting changes to the database?

Comment: I guess it depends on what "conflicting" means.  I'm not sure if SQL server via Access supports record level locking (you'll have to do research on that), but SQL server certainly has its own mechanism to avoid conflicts or corruption.  But if this is a concern for you, how is it handled now?  Even Access doesn't prevent one client from changing a record, then later having another client change the same record *in all cases*.  Only if the current record is being edited and locked does it prevent such changes, but do the automated updates via LabView client conflict? All the best in research.